# cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'

Tags: c#, mongodb

I upgraded Mongodb driver to the newest 2.0 and my application used to work failed with the error below:

> cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'

The source code is below:

```
public IQueryable<Registration> Registrations
{
    get 
    { 
        return db
            .GetCollection<Registration>("Registrations")
            .AsQueryable<Registration>(); 
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

In the new MongoDB Driver, the entire thing is now based on async methods, so the old methods for querying data no longer apply.

Basically, you would want to create an MongoRepository class, with a find method, and that repository could have the following Find method:

```cs
public class MongoRepository<T>
{

    protected IMongoCollection<T> _collection;

    public MongoRepository(string collectionName) 
    {
        // Get your mongo client and database objects here.
        _collection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    }

    public async Task<IList<T>> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
    {
        // Return the enumerable of the collection
        return await _collection.Find<T>(query).ToListAsync();
    }

}
```

This could then be implemented like so:

```cs
MongoRepository<Registration> repo = new MongoRepository("Registrations");
IList<Registration> registrations = repo.Find(i => i.SomeProperty == true);
```

There is some good information on how the changes to the API can be implemented here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/upgrading/

Comment: Any where can find a complete working MongoDb driver 2.0 C# example?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of for the latest driver. Note, that example I posted above makes use of the Repository pattern, which is not a MongoDB specific pattern. You can however find more information on the new driver details here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/ and http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/expressions/

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it will work in 2.0, but in 2.3 all you have to do, is to insert `using MongoDB.Driver`.

This namespace contains `IMongoCollectionExtensions` that provides `AsQueryable<T>` functionality to `IMongoCollection<T>`.

See [MongoDB Driver's GitHub page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/IMongoCollectionExtensions.cs).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collection.Find(builder.Where(x => true)).ToListAsync();`