# Convert IMongoCollection to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mongodb, xamarin.forms, type-conversion, observablecollection

Not able to convert `IMongoCollection<MatchDocument>` to `ObservableCollection<MatchDocument>`

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
var DB = client.GetDatabase("MTR");
var Collection = DB.GetCollection<MatchDocument>("MATCHES");
App.Profiles = new ObservableCollection<MatchDocument>(Collection);
```

Comment: are you getting an error?  If so, why aren't you telling us what the error is?  ObservableCollection constructor accepts an IEnumerable or List, is IMongoCollection either of those?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection.Find<MatchDocument>(query).ToListAsync()`:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    var DB = client.GetDatabase("MTR");
    var Collection = DB.GetCollection<MatchDocument>("MATCHES");

    Task<IList<MatchDocument>> doc = await Collection.Find<MatchDocument>(query).ToListAsync();

    ObservableCollection<MatchDocument> Profiles = new ObservableCollection<MatchDocument>(doc.Result);
```

Refer: [cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158700/cannot-convert-from-mongodb-driver-imongocollection-to-system-collections-g)

Comment: Task<IList<MatchDocument>> doc = await Collection.Find<MatchDocument>(query).ToListAsync();
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MatchDocument>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MatchDocument>>'

Comment: You get this error at runtime? It works well on my side.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the exception.

Comment: Can you share me a Minimal, Reproducible Example? I can't reproduce the issue on my side.